# jQuery: set opacity on div but don't apply to anchor tag inside div

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to change the opacity of a div as people click on links (not inside the div).  So I am setting the opacity to start with, and then changing it as need in my script.

Here is my initial setting:

```
$('#config-title5a').css('background', '#ccc url(http://www.configureyourlaser.com/images/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 -10px').css({ opacity: 0.3 });
$('a#coolingtip').css({ opacity: 1.0});
```

`a#coolingtip` is the anchor inside the div, which is called `#config-title5a`.  Currently, this script changes the opacity on everything.  How do I get it to apply the opacity change to the div, but not the anchor tag inside the div?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="config-title5">
Wavelength</div>
<div id="config-title5a">
<a id="wavelengthtip" title="Wavelength" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/views/tooltips/wavelengthtip.php" rel="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/views/tooltips/wavelengthtip.php">Learn More ›</a></div>
```

Comment: The reason I want to do this is so that the user knows the tooltip in the div is always available for clicking.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. Afaik, the maximum opacity an element can have is the one of its parent element. I mean, of course you can set a children's opacity to 1, but the parent's opacity would still be applied to the child.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you set the opacity on the parent (enclosing) element, it will affect all of the children.

One way to get around this might be to add an absolutely positioned layer to the div (an opacity layer), whose depth is less than your child element(s).

For example:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-elements">
      // this is the stuff that should remain visible
  </div>
  <div class="opacity-layer"></div>
</div>
```

And your CSS might look like this:

```
.parent {
  position:relative;
}

.opacity-layer {
  position:absolute;
  /* your opacity settings here */
}

.child-elements {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is You can't. setting the opacity on an element means any child elements opacity is affected.

Perhaps you could just set opacity on the other child elements like so:

```
$('#config-title5a *:not(#coolingtip)').css({
    'opacity': '0.3'
});

$('#config-title5a').css({
    'background': '#ccc url(http://www.configureyourlaser.com/images/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 -10px'
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that sets the opacity of the whole div to 1.0.  Is there a syntax error, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/L75Ps/1/

```
$("#config-title5a").css({opacity:0});

var link = $("a#coolingtip").detach();
$("#config-title5a").after(link);
```

Comment: This puts the link outside the div.  How do I keep the link inside the div?